# Can I add external methods in Python for a Django Project?

Tags: python, django, view

I want to make a Django application with my Cryptography projects for the school? How can I import a python applicatio to the views in DJango?

Comment: Did you try using `import`?

Answer (score 1):

Add the app name in settings.py file
in installed apps,

Then just try

```
from appname.views import methodname
```

Comment: actually you dont event need to create an app. Just `import library` should be sufficient.